# how to use protected in parent classes in php?

Tags: php

In this tutorial(http://www.techflirt.com/tutorials/oop-in-php/visibility-in-php-classes.html), it is said:

> Protected: Method or variable with protected visibility can only be
>   access in the derived class. Or in other word in child class.
>   Protected will be used in the process of inheritance.

here(http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) it is said:

> protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by
>   inherited and parent classes.

We often use Protected in inherited classes, So I wonder how does this work: protected be accessed by **parent** classes, can anyone give me an example? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`protected` really allows any class in the inheritance chain access. There's only one case really where a child property or method would/should be accessed by a parent: the parent declares and calls a `protected` method and the child *overrides* it.

```
class Foo {

    public function bar() {
        $this->baz();
    }

    protected function baz() { }

}

class Child extends Foo {

    protected function baz() {
        echo 'Ha!';
    }

}
```

When calling `$child->bar()`, this requires that `Foo::bar` can access `Child::baz`. A parent should not in any other way "know" about its children and hence have no need to access something of them.

Comment: it seems we do not need this function in class Foo: `protected function baz() { }`, we can just use below codes as one example on how protected be accessed by parent class, `<?php
class Foo {
    public function bar() {
        $this->baz();
    }
}

class Child extends Foo {
    protected function baz() {
        echo 'Ha!';
    }
}
$obj = new Child();
$obj ->bar();`

Comment: The point is that `Foo` should declare `baz()`, otherwise it shouldn't call it! A class cannot simply call a method which doesn't exist and expect a child to implement it (well, it *can*, but it's chaos).

Answer (score 2):

Protected can be access from the class that defines it any any inherited classes.

For example

```
 class test {
     protected function foo() {

     }

     public function foobar() {
          $this->foo(); //is allowed here
     }
 }

 class testa extends test {
     public function bar() {
          $this->foo(); //is allowed here
     }
 }
```